# is it possible to pass values in step function in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, global-variables, aws-step-functions

I have multiple lambda functions executing in a step function, is it possible to pass a variable from one lambda to other lambdas through a global variable in step function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, whenever a lambda returns a value you can add it to the output, which becomes input to the next step in the step function. the return value gets added to resultpath variable.